# iOS Black screen when close modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a tabbar controller and suppose if the user goes to 3rd tab and in 3rd view controller, User presses a button and there I present the view controller as modal .

Now if user switched the tab let say tab 1 or 2 without closing the modally presented view controller, and mean while he comes back to tab 3, the user will still able to see the modally presented view controller, now if user closes the modally presented view controller here, then there is a black screen instead of view controller that opened the modally presented view controller.

The possible work around is that I hide the tabbar controller so that user must close modally presented the view controller first. but it is not the requirement right now. Due to some reasons I can not hide bottom tab bar controller.

Please suggest me how to do following

1. First of all when user switches tab after opening modally presented view controller, so when he closes the modally presented vc he must see the screen at the back
2. If point no 1 is not possible so when user goes back again to tab 3 (in which he started modally presented VC) there should not be modally presented view controller. In other words when user switched the tab and the modally presented view controller is opened, it must close, before moving to other tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

**Option 1:** Creating subclass of UITabBarController

```
class MyTabBar: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let currentlySelectedViewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] as? YourThirdTabViewController,
           let presentedViewController = currentlySelectedViewController.presentedViewController {
            presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Here I am assuming that I have my own sub class of `UITabBarController` which is set as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` using `self.delegate = self` in view didLoad.

**Option 2:** Make TabBarController's ViewController `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in their `ViewDidLoad`

If you dont wanna have your own subclass of `UITabBarController` all you have to do is simply set your self as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in each `ViewController`'s `ViewDidLoad`

You can have a common protocol or extension to `UIViewController` and confirm `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to avoid code duplication if you decide to go down the path of not subclassing `UITabBarController`

```
protocol TabBarControllerProtocol: UITabBarControllerDelegate where Self: UIViewController {}

extension TabBarControllerProtocol {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let currentlySelectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex ?? 0] as? SomeViewController,
           let presentedViewController = currentlySelectedViewController.presentedViewController {
            presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In whichever ViewController, you want this logic to kick in you can say

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: TabBarControllerProtocol {}
```

Thats it.

`shouldSelect viewController` gets called every time user taps on tab to switch.

The if condition checks if `ViewController` at selectedIndex (already selected not the new one) is viewController of specific interest or not and also checks if this view controller has presented anything or not, if it has presented it will call dismiss on it

This way when user switches tab from 3rd tab to any other tab, if third tab VC has presented another view controller modally it will dismiss it before it switches tab.

Comment: no for now I have to made this change in only one view controller. SO you idea of making self as UITabBarControllerDelegate can work. 

So now just a little thing to ask, How to make my view controller as UITabBarControllerDelegate.

Comment: @a-s-ali: I have updated my answer, check Option 2

Comment: Thanks that the great answer

Comment: yes yes sure, just let me try the solution

Comment: dude can you tell me how to check if the modally presented view controller is visible/attached while changing tab

Comment: Not really sure if I got your question right, there are situation when you present a view controller but its not visible? `self. presentedViewController` will return a view controller only if there is a ViewController presented, it shouldnt technically matter if its visible or not, you are supposed to dismiss all the presented VCs correct? thats why i did not add any additional checks